# Running both AQXMLParser as well as NSXMLParser in the same application

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am trying to run an instance of AQXMLParser in the background thread while also running an instance of NSXMLParser on an independent thread. However, if the NSXMLParser is started while the AQXMLParser has not completed parsing, then the app crashes at the xmlparsechunk method.

I've tried everything from GCD to performSelectorinBackground.

The only time this crash doesn't happen is when I run either of them on the main thread.

I've been working real hard to resolve the issue, but haven't had any luck yet.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered wrapping the critical area of code (where the crash consistently occurs) with an NSLock? That way, each process can access that specific section only if the other is not using it.

Comment: well...i haven't tried NSLock yet, but I don't know if NSXMLParser and AQXMLParser share any parts of the code with each other, so not sure if that would work.

Comment: I would look into the option of AQXMLParser calling public methods of NSXMLParser